# Find the derivative of the solution to the I.V.P $ \binom{x}{y}’ = \binom{x(a-x)}{x} $ with respect to $a$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Find the derivative of the solution to the following I.V.P with respect to $a$, at $a = 1$.

$$
\binom{x}{y}(0) = \binom{1}{0}
$$
$$
\binom{x}{y}’ = \binom{x(a-x)}{x}
$$

What i tried:

---

Let $a = 1$

Substitute:

$$
z = \frac{\partial x}{\partial a}, f = \frac{\partial y}{\partial a}
$$

Therefore i get:

$$
\binom{z}{f}’ = \binom{z-2xz}{z}
$$

Now, i have the term “$-2xz$” which is a bit problematic.

Did i start right or there is another way? How do i proceed? Maybe i can substitute $x$ using the initial conditions somehow?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I'd go there brutally. As you see, only the first equation $x'=x(a-x)$ is really important. Once you have it, you can calculate y. But $x' = a x - x^2$ is a Bernoulli equation, which suggests that you replace $z = 1/x$. Then $z' = -x'/x^2 = -a/x + 1 = 1 - a z$ which is easy to solve by hand. The replace back (attention to signs!) Once you know x(a, t), take derivatives!

Answer (score 0):

In the case where the parameter is inside the equation, you need also to include its derivative in the derived equation. Here
$$
\dot z=\dot x_a=(ax-x^2)_a=x+ax_a-2xx_a=x+az-2xz.
$$